# How to automatically save PMC full text to disk through BioPython?

Tags: python, bioinformatics, biopython, pubmed

Is there a way to download and save the XML files that the Entrez module returns to local disk? What I am currently doing is :

```
fetch = Entrez.efetch(db='pmc',
                     resetmode='xml',
                     id=ids,
                     rettype='full')
article =  fetch.read()
```

Then saving `article` which is a `str` object as an xml file through Python's write function.

Does BioPython provide a way to automatically download the files onto the disk?

Comment: Why don't you just query efetch directly? like https://eutils.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/entrez/eutils/efetch.fcgi?db=protein&id=15718680,157427902,119703751

Comment: I want to download a large amount of PMC papers and NCBI has some rules about handling bulk API requests which I don't have time to implement. BioPython has already implemented them so I wanted to know if BioPython had the download feature.

Comment: I think "resetmode" should be "retmode".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think Biopython provides a way to do this, but it doesn't need to as you can do this without first saving to a string:

```
fetch = Entrez.efetch(db='pmc',
                 resetmode='xml',
                 id=ids,
                 rettype='full')

with open('fileNameToSave.xml', 'w') as f:
    f.write(fetch.read())
```

An alternative approach, as Chris_Rands points out in his comment, is to get a file directly via a URL:

```
https://eutils.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/entrez/eutils/efetch.fcgi?db=protein&id=15718680
```

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I'd done. I needed the str object in later analysis so I saved it to a string first.